# Can I use StreamField editor outside admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I ran into problems trying to build a `StreamField`-based `WYSIWYG` editor.

I want users to write their articles without giving them access to the admin panel. Is it even possible?